# ruby rails aquarium syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax-error

i having an issue with aquarium syntax for a rails app. its an app that i cloned from a github repository that i pushed it to, and it was working fine. im the only one pushing updates

========================

## this is the error i get when i try to run rails s

/Users/jcollyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.0.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require': /Users/jcollyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/aquarium-0.3.0/lib/aquarium/aspects/exclusion_handler.rb:34: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_then or ',' or ';' or '\n' (SyntaxError)
            when String: type_or_object.name.eql?(t)
                        ^
/Users/jcollyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/aquarium-0.3.0/lib/aquarium/aspects/exclusion_handler.rb:35: syntax error, unexpected keyword_when, expecting keyword_end
            when Symbol: type_or_object.name.eql?(t.to_s)
                ^
/Users/jcollyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/aquarium-0.3.0/lib/aquarium/aspects/exclusion_handler.rb:36: syntax error, unexpected keyword_when, expecting keyword_end
            when Regexp: type_or_object.name =~ t
                ^
/Users/jcollyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/aquarium-0.3.0/lib/aquarium/aspects/exclusion_handler.rb:37: syntax error, unexpected keyword_else, expecting keyword_end
            else type_or_object == t
                ^
/Users/jcollyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/aquarium-0.3.0/lib/aquarium/aspects/exclusion_handler.rb:61: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end
    from /Users/jcollyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.0.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in`block in require'
    from /Users/jcollyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.0.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
    from /Users/jcollyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.0.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:593:in`new_constants_in'
    from /Users/jcollyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.0.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/jcollyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.0.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in`require'
    from /Users/jcollyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/aquarium-0.3.0/lib/aquarium/aspects/aspect.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/jcollyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.0.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in`require'
    from /Users/jcollyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.0.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `block in require'
    from /Users/jcollyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.0.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in`block in load_dependency'
    from /Users/jcollyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.0.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:593:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Users/jcollyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.0.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in`load_dependency'
    from /Users/jcollyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.0.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /Users/jcollyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/aquarium-0.3.0/lib/aquarium/aspects.rb:2:in`'
    from /Users/jcollyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.0.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /Users/jcollyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.0.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in`block in require'
    from /Users/jcollyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.0.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
    from /Users/jcollyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.0.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:593:in`new_constants_in'
    from /Users/jcollyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.0.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/jcollyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.0.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in`require'
    from /Users/jcollyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/aquarium-0.3.0/lib/aquarium.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/jcollyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in`require'
    from /Users/jcollyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/jcollyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in`each'
    from /Users/jcollyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
    from /Users/jcollyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in`each'
    from /Users/jcollyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/jcollyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler.rb:128:in`require'
    from /Users/jcollyer/Documents/projects/hughes/hughes_cms/Funeral-Homes/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/jcollyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in`require'
    from /Users/jcollyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/jcollyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in`tap'
    from /Users/jcollyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in`require'
    from script/rails:6:in `'

## my gem file

source 'http://rubygems.org'

- gem 'rails', '3.0.10'
- gem 'sqlite3'
- gem 'mysql2','< 0.3'
- gem 'devise'
- gem 'simple-navigation'
- gem 'paperclip', '~> 2.4'
- gem 'jquery-rails', '>= 1.0.12'
- gem 'galetahub-simple_captcha', require: "simple_captcha"
- gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0'
- gem 'aquarium'
- gem "meta_search"

group :test, :development do
- gem "rspec-rails", "~> 2.6"
- gem "autotest"
- gem 'factory_girl'
end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify version of aquarium gem

```
gem "aquarium", "~> 0.5.1"
```

ruby 1.9.3 supports only from version 0.5.1

> V0.5.1 (May 1, 2012): Now supports Ruby 1.9.3 and JRuby 1.6.7.

**Source** http://aquarium.rubyforge.org/

Or should I say use ruby-1.8.7 for this app instead of ruby-1.9.3. Because rails 3.0 can be incompatible with ruby-1.9.3